# Apple Script to set Primary Button, Secondary Button and other properties for Mouse Preference

Tags: applescript

Can anyone suggest me:

> How to set Primary Button, Secondary
>   Button and other properties of Mouse
>   Preference via AppleScript?

I have now tried this, script:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        click menu item "Mouse" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
        tell window "Mouse"
            set value of pop up button 1 to "Primary Button"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

but it is giving this error message:

> System Events got an error: Can't get
>   pop up button 1 of window "Mouse" of
>   process "System Preferences". Invalid
>   index.

Can anyone suggest me where I may be wrong or some better trick to implement it?

Thanks,

Miraaj

Comment: See the amendment to my answer below

Comment: @philip .... checked! I have posted the whole script which I am trying... what else should I provide you to help me to resolve the issues and implement my simple requirement: how to set some action say "Primary Button" to "Left Mouse Button" in Mouse Preference pane?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my version which eliminates the need for the "keyboard tricks" as shown in the post from Christopher Kemp above. Plus it has a few extra things thrown in like running a check to make sure assistive devices is set to 'on', and a dialog box so you can select whether you want the mouse to be set as left or right handed. Hope it helps :)

P.S. This is for 10.6 (Snow Leopard)...you'd have to change it slightly to suit the 10.5 (Leopard) preference pane differences.

--

```
# check 'Enable access for assistive devices' is ON

tell application "System Events"

if UI elements enabled then

    # open dialog
    set question to display dialog "Select your mouse preference." buttons {"Left Handed", "Right Handed", "Cancel"} default button 3 with title "Mouse Switch"

    set answer to button returned of question

    if answer is equal to "Left Handed" then

        # open Mouse preferences & set left button to Secondary
        tell application "System Preferences"

            activate
            reveal pane "Mouse"

        end tell

        tell application "System Events"

            tell process "System Preferences"

                # set Secondary Button
                click pop up button 4 of group 1 of window "Mouse"
                click menu item "Secondary Button" of menu of pop up button 4 of group 1 of window "Mouse"
                # set Primary Button
                click pop up button 5 of group 1 of window "Mouse"
                click menu item "Primary Button" of menu of pop up button 5 of group 1 of window "Mouse"

            end tell

        end tell

        tell application "System Preferences" to quit

        display dialog "Your mouse is now set to: Left Handed" buttons {"OK"}

    end if

    if answer is equal to "Right Handed" then

        # open Mouse preferences & set right button to Secondary
        tell application "System Preferences"

            activate
            reveal pane "Mouse"

        end tell

        tell application "System Events"

            tell process "System Preferences"

                # set Secondary Button
                click pop up button 5 of group 1 of window "Mouse"
                click menu item "Secondary Button" of menu of pop up button 5 of group 1 of window "Mouse"
                # set Primary Button
                click pop up button 4 of group 1 of window "Mouse"
                click menu item "Primary Button" of menu of pop up button 4 of group 1 of window "Mouse"

            end tell

        end tell

        tell application "System Preferences" to quit

        display dialog "Your mouse is now set to: Right Handed" buttons {"OK"}

    end if

    # if 'Enable access for assistive devices' is OFF show error
else

    display dialog "Please select 'Enable access for assistive devices' from the Universal Access preference pane to run this script." buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon caution

end if

end tell
```

Comment: Tip: You can add this script to the OS X menu bar by following [these steps](http://superuser.com/a/506808/114327).

Answer (score 1):

goto system preferences, universal access pane, select "Enable access for assistive devices"

this needs to be enable on an mac that is going to run as script the uses GUI scripting

**EDIT**

now that you have done that you can change your script since it got an error, have your script click the radio button like so

```
  tell application "System Preferences"
   activate
   set current pane to first pane whose name is "Mouse"
  end tell

  tell application "System Events"
   tell process "System Preferences"
    try
     click radio button "Left" of every radio group of window "Mouse"
    on error theError
     --An error occured
     display dialog ("Sorry, an error occured while altering Keyboard and Mouse settings:" & return & theError) buttons "OK" default button "OK"
    end try
   end tell
  end tell
```

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

check out [Scriptable System Preferences](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/features/system-prefs.html) you may find that thread more helpful

Comment: thanks for your reply... but now I am getting this error message: Can’t set «class actT» of "left mouse button" to "Primary Button", can you suggest me where I may be wrong?

Comment: thanks for the script... I tried it, but getting following error message: System Events got an error: Can't get radio group 1 of window "Mouse" of process "System Preferences". Invalid index :(

Comment: what version of mac os are you running ? do you have ui browser ?

Comment: it is MacOSX 10.6.4.. no I don't have ui browser!

Comment: the above script is not causing any error now :), but it is not performing the action which I want: to set some action say "Primary Button" to "Left Mouse Button" in Mouse Preference pane :(

Comment: thats what the script does its set the primary button to "Left" mouse 
change the click line to 
click radio button "Right" of every radio group of window "Mouse" and see it work

Comment: thanx.. mcgrailm for the link, I will definitely look at it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do exactly what that error message says. Look under Universal Access in System Preferences, and you will see a checkbox for "Enable access for assistive devices". I'll leave it as an exercise to you to sort out how to enable that via Applescript.

---

Please post all of the relevant code. There are lot of reason why that might not work. The Universal Access pane may not be active, the button or the type may not be accessible via Applescript (the latter being more than likely).

Comment: I noticed that, too, but I thought you got in before I did. So, I guess you read through the questions first thing in the morning when you get into work like me?

Comment: thanks for your reply... but now I am getting this error message: Can’t set «class actT» of "left mouse button" to "Primary Button", can you suggest me where I may be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work:

```
# open Mouse preferences & set right button to Secondary

tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to first pane whose name is "Mouse"
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"

            # activates drop-down menu
        click pop up button 5 of group 1 of window "Mouse"

            # page up key, to ensure we're starting at the top of the list
        key code 116

            # down arrow, to select Secondary Button from list
        key code 125

            # Return key to make selection
        key code 36

        delay 1
        click button "Show All" of group 1 of group 2 of tool bar 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

The *delay* command isn't necessary, it's just so you can visually confirm your choice. It would be nicer to "set" the value rather than doing keyboard tricks, but at least it does the job.

Comment: Incidentally, I already had Assistive Devices enabled, but I have a part to automate that in the script as well, using a shell command: do shell script "touch /private/var/db/.AccessibilityAPIEnabled" user name <insert your admin account name> password <insert your admin password> with administrator privileges. Note that the name & password DO NOT use the <> brackets, that's just to make up for the lack of formatting in replies. ;)

Comment: thanks for your reply... however when I tried the above script, it gave me this error message: Can't set pane 1 whose name = "Mouse" to pane 1 whose name = "Mouse".. I tried it on Leopard !